# How can i check sql server 'views' dependencies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, view

Is there a way that i can find out what base tables are being used by views using a custom query or stored procedure?

Comment: This has nothing to do with .net, only SQL server. The tag is a bit misleading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something you'll be doing often Red Gate SQL Dependency Tracker (no I don't work for them) is a great tool.  I think they have a trial period if you want to try it.

Answer (score 15):

You could use the sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities function to find objects referenced by a specified view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
referenced_schema_name , 
referenced_entity_name 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('Sales.vSalesPersonSalesByFiscalYears', 'OBJECT');
```

[image]

Also, there is the sys.sql_expression_dependencies system view where you can specify a table name and a type of the referencing object:

```
SELECT 
referencing_object_name = o.name, 
referencing_object_type_desc = o.type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies se 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON se.referencing_id = o.[object_id] 
WHERE referenced_entity_name = 'Person' AND o.type_desc = 'View'
```

[image]

To avoid "manual" work you could also use [ApexSQL Clean](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx), a SQL Server tool that can find all internal and external dependencies. In the results pane select an object and see all objects that depend on the selected object, and objects on which the selected object depends on:

[image]

You can also filter objects  and visualize dependencies:

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [sql_dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402(SQL.90).aspx) view:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(referenced_major_id) as DependantObject
from sys.sql_dependencies
where object_id = object_id('YourViewName')
```

To recursively retrieve dependencies (f.e., if you select from a view, this would find the tables that the other view references):

```
with deps (child, parent) as (
    select d.object_id, d.referenced_major_id
    from sys.sql_dependencies d
    where d.object_id = object_id('YourViewName')
    union all
    select d.object_id, d.referenced_major_id
    from sys.sql_dependencies d
    inner join deps on deps.parent = d.object_id
)
select OBJECT_NAME(parent)
from deps
```

This method is not fool-proof. For example, if you rename an object using [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx), its dependencies are not updated.

Comment: i get no results when i run this

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  Maybe you could post the definition of the view?

Comment: yes it works for only views which i created but for other views created by other developers (to which i have access) i get 0 records.

Comment: If the views created by other developers are in another schema, try to qualify the view name like `where d.object_id = object_id('OtherDevSchema.OtherDevView')`

Comment: Just double checking, are you aware of the difference between a schema and a database?  The syntax is `database.schema.object`, for example `MyDb.MySchema.MyView`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good explanation: 
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=277

Comment: i get no results when i create and run that sp

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using sys.sql_expression_dependencies in SQL-Server >= 2008 (R1+)

 **Note: This will take 30 seconds or more.**

If you **only** want the views, **remove the scalar + table-valued functions** ( 'FN' and 'IF').

A table-valued function can be a dependency of a view and vice-versa, plus the view/tvf may depend on scalar functions.

```
;WITH TFV_Dependencies AS 
(
    SELECT 
         --OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sysdep.referencing_id) AS Referencing_Schema 
         ReferencingO.object_id AS ReferencingObject_Id 
        ,sysschema.name AS Referencing_Schema 
        ,ReferencingO.name AS Referencing_Object_Name 
        ,sysdep.referenced_schema_name AS Referenced_Schema 
        ,sysdep.referenced_entity_name AS Referenced_Object_Name 
        --,ReferencingO.type
        ,ReferencedO.name AS RefName 
        --,ReferencedO.type AS RefType
    FROM sys.objects as ReferencingO 

    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS sysschema 
        ON sysschema.schema_id = ReferencingO.schema_id 

    LEFT JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sysdep 
    LEFT JOIN sys.objects as ReferencedO 
        ON ReferencedO.name = sysdep.referenced_entity_name 
        ON sysdep.referencing_id = ReferencingO.object_id 
        AND ReferencingO.name <> sysdep.referenced_entity_name 
        --AND ReferencedO.type <> 'U' 
        AND ReferencedO.type IN ( 'IF', 'FN', 'V' ) 

    WHERE (1=1) 
    --AND ReferencingO.type NOT IN ('PK','F','UQ','SQ','D','IT', 'S')
    --AND ReferencingO.type IN ( 'U', 'V', 'FN', 'IF', 'P') 
    AND ReferencingO.type IN ( 'IF', 'FN', 'V' ) 
    AND ReferencingO.name NOT IN 
    (
         'dt_adduserobject'
        ,'dt_droppropertiesbyid'
        ,'dt_dropuserobjectbyid'
        ,'dt_generateansiname'
        ,'dt_getobjwithprop'
        ,'dt_getobjwithprop_u'
        ,'dt_getpropertiesbyid'
        ,'dt_getpropertiesbyid_u'
        ,'dt_setpropertybyid'
        ,'dt_setpropertybyid_u'
        ,'dt_verstamp006'
        ,'dt_verstamp007'

        ,'sp_helpdiagrams'
        ,'sp_creatediagram'
        ,'sp_alterdiagram'
        ,'sp_renamediagram'
        ,'sp_dropdiagram'

        ,'sp_helpdiagramdefinition'
        ,'fn_diagramobjects'
    ) 

) 

,DependencyGroup AS 
( 
    -- base case 
    SELECT 
         ReferencingObject_Id AS ObjectId 
        ,Referencing_Object_Name AS ObjectName  
        ,Referencing_Schema AS ObjectSchema 
        ,1 AS Lvl 
    FROM TFV_Dependencies 
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND Referenced_Object_Name IS NULL 

    -- recursive case
    UNION ALL 

   SELECT 
         d.ReferencingObject_Id AS ObjectId 
        ,d.Referencing_Object_Name AS ObjectName 
        ,d.Referencing_Schema AS ObjectSchema 
        ,r.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl 
    FROM TFV_Dependencies AS d 
    INNER JOIN DependencyGroup AS r 
        ON r.ObjectName = d.Referenced_Object_Name 
) 
,
CTE AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 999999999999999999 
         MAX(Lvl) AS Lvl 
        ,ObjectId 
        ,ObjectSchema
        ,ObjectName 
        --,'DELETE FROM [' + REPLACE(ObjectName, '''', '''''') + ']; ' AS DeleteCmd 
    FROM DependencyGroup 

    GROUP BY ObjectId, ObjectSchema, ObjectName 
)

SELECT 
     CTE.Lvl
    ,CTE.ObjectSchema AS SPECIFIC_SCHEMA 
    ,CTE.ObjectName AS SPECIFIC_NAME 
    ,sysSqlModules.definition AS ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM CTE 

LEFT JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sysSqlModules 
    ON sysSqlModules.object_id = CTE.ObjectId 

ORDER BY Lvl, ObjectSchema, ObjectName 

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct
    v.table_name AS ViewName,
    re.referenced_entity_name
FROM information_schema.views v
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + v.table_name,'OBJECT') re
WHERE re.referenced_class = 1
```

This works for me!